# IONIC - Decimal keyboard on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, html, cordova, ionic-framework

I want to show a keyboard with a decimal separator. I have tried several solutions but none of them worked.

The closest I got was using the telephone input type. But instead of having a "." as a decimal separator, there is a "Pause" button that when you click on it the output is actually a ".", but I can't use that since it would be too misleading for my users.

http://ionicframework.com/html5-input-types/#tel

Using the code below I also got very close to what I want, but there wasn't any decimal separator.

```
<input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*">
```

The result:

[image: No decimal separator]

This is what I want:

[image: What I want]

Any ideas on how I can achieve it?

Comment: try:

**<label class="item item-input">
  <span class="input-label">Telephone</span>
  <input type="tel">
</label>**

instead of  **<input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*">**

Comment: or directly use **<input type="tel">**

Comment: How about adding the decimal separator manually using Javascript?

Comment: @Naitik There is no decimal separator using <input type="TEL"> :(

Comment: @Abhishek Jain, how can I do that? Any suggestions?

Comment: I mean adding commas to the input field, (not the popup keyboard numpad) by checking the length of the string and appending commas suitably.

Comment: http://blog.pamelafox.org/2012/05/triggering-numeric-keyboards-with-html5.html will be your test...

Comment: @Abhishek Jain, Unfortunately I can't do that because the user can type numbers like: 15; 15,2; 150000000; 1500000000,2345. I don't have a number pattern.

Comment: @Naitik, That is what I have right now, but this isn't just a number keyboard.

Comment: Aah. I wrongly assumed you meant to add a _currency_ comma separator.

Comment: @Abhishek Jain, no worries, thank you very much though!